# Set modelsim intel starter VHDL version to 2008

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm trying to use something from `VHDL 2008` (it can be done with 2002, of course, but it's much cleaner in 2008). If I compile the file in the command line setting the version manually it succeeds, but trying to get modelsim to compile it fails because the version is set as 2002.

When I try accessing the **compile options**, in the **compile** menu, it's grayed out.

Modelsim version is **10.5b intel starter** (just updated because of this) and the files are part of a project. Is this a paid feature, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: On the command line it is `vcom -2008 ...`. You can also edit the `modelsim.ini` file and change the default VHDL version. Search for the line `VHDL93 = ...` and replace it by `VHDL93 = 2008` (yes, this variable name is... strange). I cannot help with the graphical user interface, I never use it for compilation.

Comment: Editing the `modelsim.ini` was exactly what I needed. Worth noting that if the project was already created, the settings are copied to `project_directory/project_name.mpf`, and that takes priority.
(I do need to be less dependent on GUIs, but I find it a lot more convenient.)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there some way to change that via command line, rather than modifying the modelsim.ini file?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it through the GUI by **right clicking on the files** you want to compile with VHDL 2008 in your Project view, and selecting *Properties...* to access the **Project Compiler Settings**.

Then select **VHDL > Language Syntax > Use 1076-2008**.

Comment: It seems that simply setting compile switches for individual files is insufficient.  I had to go to [ Settings | Compiler Settings | VHDL Input ] and select [ VHDL 2008 ].  Otherwise the Quartus tcl script modelsim.tcl (in the installation directory) adds "-93" to the autogenerated vcom command lines, which overrides any "VHDL93" specifications in any of the  modelsim.ini files.  Changing the above settings resulted in "-2008" instead.

Answer (score 1):

use the command

```
vcom -2008 filename.vhd
```

this will force Modelsim to use VHDL 2008